# In remix Ide what does this notification means? "You have not set a script to run. Set it with @custom:dev-run-script NatSpec tag"

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix

> You have not set a script to run. Set it with @custom:dev-run-script NatSpec tag

[The notification message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jkyx.png)

I have written a simple program of Hello World in the Remix IDE.

Answer (score 5):

It's an easy fix -
Just add these lines before declaring your contract.

```html
  /**
   * @title ContractName
   * @dev ContractDescription
   * @custom:dev-run-script file_path
   */
  contract ContractName {}
```

Learn more from [here](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_js_scripts.html)

Answer (score 1):

The default workshop includes two scripts to deploy contracts:
`scripts/deploy_with_ethers.ts`
`scripts/deploy_with_web3.ts`

If you choose the first one, you have to edit it to set the name of the contract to edit, the default value is `Storage` from `1_Storage.sol`.

```js
import { deploy } from './ethers-lib'

(async () => {
    try {
        const result = await deploy('Storage', [])
        console.log(`address: ${result.address}`)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
    }
  })()
```

Then you add at the beginning of your contract:

```
  /**
   * @title ContractName
   * @dev ContractDescription
   * @custom:dev-run-script scripts/deploy_with_ethers.ts
   */
  contract ContractName {}
```

Now when you hit `control+shift+S`, the contract is saved and published to the network configured in the "Deploy & run transaction" section (last icon from top to bottom on the left margin).